# Did the update fix the multiple Panna City Medicine levels bug?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Prior to the recent update fixing the holiday decoration bug, I have seen people say that they built more than one Panna City Medicine Level due to their decorations resetting and being able to make the same achievements over again.  I'm closing in on that situation myself, and I want to know if the recent update fixed this bug, or am I going to have two Panna City Medicine levels?

Comment: It would also have been nice if they restored you to 35 levels decorated if you already had Panna City Medicine built.  Then you could continue to earn Bux instead of rebuilding a quest you had already completed!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an event that is now over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer my own question.  As of 1.2.2234 it is not fixed.  I now have two copies of Panna City Medicine.  When I asked the question, I only had one copy, but having been reset by the bug, I decorated 35 levels AGAIN, and was given a second copy of the floor.  This event took place AFTER the update fixing the reset bug.

I put in a request for support to Disney.  I'm expecting a personal phone call from Mickey Mouse any minute now.

The negative here is simple:  As of the current iteration of the game, there are not enough bitizens to staff all of the jobs.  With the addition of Panna City Medicine, it creates 3 more job slots than the number of residential slots.  Adding a second copy, now compounds the problem to 6 total jobs that have no one to fill them.

Update from Disney Customer Support:

> At this time we don't have the ability to adjust or alter your in-game
>   content, so we won't be able to remove the second level.
>
> Tiny Death Star's extra levels (that you can purchase from the Menu)
>   were created so that you could customize your Death Star further.
>   While you may have run out of Apartment levels to staff your Jobs, we
>   hope to have more available in the future. If we add more, it should
>   be via a new update so keep an eye on your device! Hopefully a future
>   update will also include the ability to delete levels so you can get
>   rid of levels you no longer care to have.
>
> If you have any other questions, please don't hesitate to let us know.

Comment: If you stock a product and then remove the bitizen for that job, the store will continue to sell that stock. So with extra jobs you could shuffle bitizens around a lot and still make the same amount as if you permanently filled the positions.

Comment: Yes.  But it comes at the expense of a lot of time spent "gardening."

Answer (score 1):

It is not fixed in 1.2.1

I still have two Panna City levels

I put in a support ticket with Disney for this.  So far I have only received canned responses.

Comment: Did you create the second one before or after the update?

Comment: Second one was created after the update.

Comment: I show the current version as 1.2.2344.  Are you using that version?

Comment: Got the following from Disney::
At this time we do not have the capabilities to alter or change anything within your Tiny Death Star game. The game is still very new, and you never know what sorts of features will become available in the future. In the meantime, having this extra level will get you more credits if you have enough Bitizens to staff it!

Comment: Frustrating!!!  Very frustrating!!!  +1 for the info.